# Webpack Imported Module is not a function on stream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have added two files to my React project: ndjson-stream-reader.js and usage.js. I got them from here: https://gist.github.com/ornicar/a097406810939cf7be1df8ea30e94f3e

They are supposed to import chess games from lichess, at least that is my interpretation of what it is meant to do..

When I run usage.js from a button using an onClick event, I get the following error:

> TypeError: _library_ndjson_stream_reader__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...) is not a function

I have no idea of even where to begin with this. Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `ndjson-stream-reader.js` isn't in a module format, ie it doesn't export anything so there is nothing to import

Comment: Stupid me! Thanks for pointing that out. I got it importing now. I am trying to build an object of all the games from the steam. I'm a bit of a novice at fetch. To build an object of the streams, would I just do const stream = steam + fetch(etc)? Or am I way off base?